# Stacked view grouped by terms don’t work with Grafana-Framework and Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, real-time, monitoring, grafana

Is there a possibility to get the bars stacked after user?

Hey guys,
in the Elasticsearch index ‘test’ I have this data:

```
{"statement": {"type": "cook", "actor": "user1", "timestamp":  "2016-11-29T10:14:19.180600+00:00"}},
{"statement": {"type": "cook", "actor": "user1", "timestamp": "2016-11-29T15:03:59.907900+00:00"}},
{"statement": {"type": "sleep", "actor": "user1", "timestamp": "2016-11-29T14:50:29.088900+00:00"}},
{"statement": {"type": "sleep", "actor": "user2", "timestamp": "2016-11-29T15:06:38.894700+00:00"}},
{"statement": {"type": "cook", "actor": "user2", "timestamp": "2016-11-29T15:21:48.873300+00:00"}},
{"statement": {"type": "sleep", "actor": "user2", "timestamp": "2016-11-29T15:23:12.020700+00:00"}}
```

This is what i got

[This Picture shows what metric i have used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRuYY.png)

[This Picutre shows what x-axis-options i have used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0NYB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do stacked bars with your X axis mode set to series.  It only works with time mode